# How to access C# model attribute within EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I have a model like below:

```
public class CreateStockcheckJobModel
{
    [Engineer(true)]
    public EngineerModel Engineer { get; set; }
}
```

I'm rendering the `Engineer` property in a `View<CreateStockcheckJobModel>` using `Html.EditorFor(m => m.Engineer, "EngineerEditor")`.

How do I access the value in the `Engineer` attribute (in this case `true`) from within the code in my partial view (`EngineerEditor.ascx`)?

---

Below is my editor code

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="ViewUserControl<EngineerModel>" %>
<% if (PropertyImRenderingHasAttributeWithTrueBooleanValue) // What goes here?
   { %>
<p>Render one thing</p>
<% }
   else
   { %>
<p>Render another thing</p>
<% } %>
```

I'm aware of reflection, however i'm unsure how to use it as the attribute isn't added to the `EngineerModel` class it's added to the `Engineer` property of the `CreateStockcheckJobModel` class. If i could get the `PropertyInfo` that I'm rendering from the editor code then I'd be sorted, but I don't know how to get that information. If I go down the route of enumerate all properties in the `CreateStockcheckJobModel` class then I'm going to get issues if I have more than one `EngineerModel` property (one might have the attribute with `True`, another might have `False`).

Comment: What do you want to get? It seems to me, that you doing wrong to achive your aim

Comment: It's basically rendering a list of possible engineers to pick. I want the attribute to control the list of engineers available.

Comment: I thought it was a reasonable approch as it seems to be what the `DisplayFormat` attribute is doing (i.e. changing the way a control/editor is rendered based on data in the attribute)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be done easily in ASP.NET MVC 3 and later by implementing the [`IMetadataAware`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imetadataaware.aspx) interface on your custom `EngineerAttribute`:

```
public class EngineerAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public EngineerAttribute(bool isFoo)
    {
        IsFoo = isFoo;
    }

    public bool IsFoo { get; private set; }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AdditionalValues["IsFoo"] = IsFoo;
    }
}
```

and then inside the template:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="ViewUserControl<EngineerModel>" %>
<%
    var isFoo = (bool)ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["IsFoo"];
%>
<% if (isFoo) { %>
    <p>Render one thing</p>
<% } else { %>
    <p>Render another thing</p>
<% } %>
```

Unfortunately this interface doesn't exist in ASP.NET MVC 2. To achieve the same functionality you could write a custom metadata provider:

```
public class MyMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(
        IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, 
        Type containerType, 
        Func<object> modelAccessor, 
        Type modelType, 
        string propertyName
    )
    {
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
        var engineer = attributes.OfType<EngineerAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (engineer != null)
        {
            metadata.AdditionalValues["IsFoo"] = engineer.IsFoo;
        }
        return metadata;
    }
}
```

that you will register in your `Application_Start` in order to replace the default one:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MyMetadataProvider();
```

And now you could access this metadata in your template the same way as I showed earlier, using `ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["IsFoo"]`. Obviously you could put an arbitrarily complex object inside the `AdditionalValues` property, not just booleans.

Also you might find the [following article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=687) useful about metadata.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: Below is a possible way to do this but using `IMetadataAware` as described in the accepted answer is a far better way. It's usually better to avoid reflection if you can.

You can only do this via reflection. Here's a [good example](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-method-attributes-and-reflection) on how to do this for method attributes.

Code example for getting value of `EngineerAttribute` on property `Engineer`:

```
PropertyInfo pi = Model.GetType().GetProperty("Engineer");
EngineerAttribute a =
    System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(pi, typeof(EngineerAttribute));
```

Code example for getting all properties that have the attribute `[Engineer(true)]`:

```
var t = Model.GetType();
var engineerProperties =
    from p in t.GetProperties()
    let ca = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(p, typeof(EngineerAttribute))
    where ca != null && ca.BooleanProperty == true
    select p;
```

And when you have these properties, you can use an overload of [`EditorFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406462%28VS.98%29.aspx) that allows you to specify additional view data, that you can then use in your subview:

```
Html.EditorFor(m => m.Engineer, new { IsEngineer = isEngineer });
```

Comment: I know how reflection works, but I'm having trouble working out what property to get the attribute for as in the editor i only have the type `EngineerModel` not the enclosing type and the property (i.e. the attribute isn't on the `EngineerModel` it's on a property that happens to be an `EngineerModel`).

Comment: Given your edit, my problem is that in the editor the model is of type `EngineerModel` and the attribute isn't on the model, it's on the property of the enclosing model. Obviously the property name could change and there could be multiple properties with the `EngineerModel` type (so i can't just get the enclosing model type and find the property of type `EngineerModel`).

Comment: I just read the comments on the question and what you actually want is to list all properties that have `[Engineer(true)]`?

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you want... You no longer have access to the root model where the property was defined... I don't think that what you want is possible. Can't you add a property to EngineerModel that expresses the 'engineerness' of an engineer instead of applying a custom attribute?

Comment: Once I have all properties with that attribute how do I know which one the editor should be rendering? (in the case where I have multiple properties of type `EngineerModel`, each with their own `Engineer` attribute.

Comment: Re. the "Ahh how I understand..." comment. I guess adding a property is an option, although that's kind of against they way other properties are done in (such as the `DisplayFormatAttribute` type attributes).

Comment: I think all information you need is now in my answer, although it is not yet a complete solution...

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but I'd like to avoid having to duplicate code in any view that uses the editor (in your case the code to pass view data to the editor).